# How do I profile a Blazor Server app using dotTrace from Visual Studio

Tags: resharper, blazor-server-side, dottrace

I am trying to profile my Blazor server app using dotTrace and I can't find any way to have it launch the app plus display it in the browser. It launches the DOS box for the app. But no browser. And when I open Chrome and go to the url that it uses when I debug/run from Visual Studio - nothing shows.

I am able to profile by launching the app from Visual Studio, then opening dotTrace and attaching to the app. But I'd prefer to have it launch it for me. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please select the "Open URL" checkbox in your profiling configuration and paste the URL into the corresponding field?
Then start the profiling session for this configuration as usual.

Does it work for you?

Comment: I tried that and it opened the browser, but not to my web app page. I think somehow the url to the app is different when running under the profiler - is that possible?